# Select based on whether a parameter is NULL or not

Tags: sql, case

If customer id is not null then filter with the customer id provided else show all customers. I am not sure how to do this. One approach I am thinking is to use CASE statement but not sure how to write it.

```
select * from customer
where case when @customerid is null then show all customers
else customer_id = @customerid
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do what you want is:

```
select * 
from customer 
where 
    (@customerid is null OR customer_id = @customerid)
```